# Android: UnKnownHostException at httpCLient.execute

Tags: android, httpclient, unknown-host

I am getting **UnknownhostException** at **execute** step in:

```
httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.xxxx.com/contoller/method");
httpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);

java.net.UnknownHostException "www.xxxx.com"
```

Some where i read, i need to remove **http://**

but then i get this Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.
```

Comment: Did you add Internet permission?

Comment: yeah. In fact it was working yesterday, and i didn't change anything. I checked the internet connectivity, it is fine. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to open the link on pc browser.... if it works then open the link on device browser... hope it will help you to trace the where the problem is code or server